# NiFi integration with Sentry.io

Tags: apache-nifi, sentry

I am trying to catch Exceptions from nifi-app.log.

Some of the Exceptions Im not able to catch as they occurs only in top-right corner of the proccessor.

And also, I would like to send Sentry notification via **LogMessage (level: error)**

I tried to put (as mentioned in https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/logback/)

```
<appender name="SENTRY" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender">
    <options>
        <dsn>--my-DSN--</dsn>
    </options>
</appender>

<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="SENTRY" />
</root>
```

To the Nifi/conf/logback.xml, but the error is that the class
`io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender`
could not be found (ofc)

Then I though of putting **sentry-logback-1.7.5.jar** (also tried other versions and Sentry SDK 6.29.0) into the **nifi/lib/** directory, but then Im having strange error during startup:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.nifi.nar.ExtensionMapping.size()" because "extensionMapping" is null
    at org.apache.nifi.documentation.DocGenerator.generate(DocGenerator.java:61)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:788)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:172)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:83)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:332)
```

I havent found anything on that error online, and also I havent found a single try on integrate NiFi exceptions with Sentry.io

Is there anything else I can try? If I put the sentry-logback.jar anywhere else, the ClassNotFoundException is present for the SENTRY appender

Comment: what is the version of java and nifi you are using?

Comment: openjdk 17.0.8.1 2023-08-24, 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.8.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu123.04), 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.8.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu123.04, mixed mode, sharing), NiFi-1.20.0

Comment: i don't think this error connected with serenity.io library. the official nifi admin guide saying `Requires Java 8 or Java 11`.  https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#system_requirements

Comment: If I add any library to the /lib folder, I always get the NullPointerException... Do you have any library that is working for you and I can test it ?

Comment: i can add any library to /lib folder that matching java version.

Answer (score -2):

**Problem 1: ClassNotFoundException for SentryAppender**

You're getting an error saying it can't find it.sentry. log back.SentryAppender. To fix this:
Put the necessary JAR files, including sentry-log back, in the NiFi lib directory.
Ensure you're using compatible versions of the Sentry SDK and JARs that match your NiFi version.

**Problem 2: NullPointerException during NiFi Startup**

This error is happening when NiFi starts up, and it doesn't seem related to Sentry. To troubleshoot:
Double-check your NiFi configuration files (like nifi.properties and logback.xml) for any mistakes.
Make sure the JAR files in the lib directory don't have naming conflicts.
Look into any custom processors or configurations that might be causing this.

**Sentry Configuration**

Ensure your Sentry setup is correct:
Check your Sentry account and project setup and ensure your DSN (Sentry connection string) is accurate.
Review Sentry's documentation to see if there are specific settings needed for NiFi integration.

**NiFi Logging Configuration**

Make sure your logback.xml file is set up correctly:
Include the SENTRY appender configuration.
Confirm that the rest of the NiFi logging configuration is accurate.
Verify that the DSN option in the SENTRY appender configuration has the correct Sentry DSN.

**Log Placement**

When configuring Sentry, ensure you catch and report exceptions effectively. You might need to set up custom logging for NiFi components to make sure all exceptions are captured. Remember to restart NiFi after making changes.

Comment: Im sorry, but this looks like AI generated text with no real help. When the JAR is placed to /lib, the NiFi wont start, when the JAR is placed anywhere else, the ClassNotFoundException is thrown. Tried different JARs aswell (JPA drivers,MSSQL driver)